# Clear NavController backStack without knowing start destination's id

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to implement session expiry in my app. So when the user token has expired, I want to navigate to the Login Fragment and clear all existing destinations on the back stack. I know this is achievable with `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` but a lot of conditional navigation is going on and the destination to popUpTo can't be determined at the point of navigating to the Login Fragment. Is there a way to simply navigate to a new fragment and clear every other destination on the back stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:launchSingleTop="true"` in fragment action in navigation graph xml file.